# Hadoop: How do blocks get deleted after running HDFS benchmarks?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, benchmarking, hdfs

In my two-datanode setup, I am running the TestDFSIO benchmark and observing that blocks get deleted in the final stages of running the benchmark.

This seems to be part of a cleanup process that is executed when the benchmark is finishing up.  The logs confirm this with the following line:

```
hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Adding task (JOB_CLEANUP) ...
```

How does adding the JOB_CLEANUP task actually correlate to blocks/files getting deleted?

I know that TestDFSIO.java has cleanup methods, but I was not able to see how/if/when they get called when finishing up the benchmark execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The run() method of the Mapper class (provided by the Hadoop framework) calls the cleanup method:

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  setup(context);
  while (context.nextKeyValue()) {
    map(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getCurrentValue(), context);
  }
  cleanup(context);
}
```